# Using ibus tool for installing watchOS on an iWatch Series 3

Tags: ios

I downloaded the watch OS version 4.2 from IPSW.me but got a zip file.
I plan to install it via iBUS tool for for my kids and give them the watches for Christmas. i have two such watches with older versions.
I need the extension to be a an IPSW file rather than a zip file and the name to not be a bunch of hexadecimal numbers/letters.
Does anyone know where i could download the IPSW files for series 3 watches, 38mm with an ipsw extension?

Comment: Your question is off topic for SO, but out of interest, can't you just pair the watches with your phone, upgrade the firmware and then unpair/reset the watches?

Comment: yes i can. but i am trying to find a way to do it without the phone pairing . because i have an iphone and my daughters don't. i want to see if it'll work, and they can do it by themselves

Comment: If the don't have an iPhone then how are they going to use the watch?  You have to pair an Apple Watch with an iPhone before it will do anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is no firmware public available for apple watch S3 yet.the zip file are OTA file that's not ipsw file, you could not restore that by any tools